# How to load a specially formatted data file into matlab?

Tags: matlab, file-io

I need to load a data file, test.dat, into Matlab. The contents of data file are like

> *a682  1233~0.2
>     *a2345  233~0.8     345~0.2   4567~0.3
>     *a3457  345~0.9    34557~1.2  34578~0.2    9809~0.1   2345~2.9   23452~0.9    334557~1.2  234578~0.2    19809~0.1   23452~2.9   3452~0.9    4557~1.2  3578~0.2    92809~0.1   12345~2.9   232452~0.9    33557~1.6  23478~0.6    198099~2.1   234532~2.9    …

How to read this type of file into matlab, and use the terms, such as *2345 to identify a row, which links to corresponding terms, including  233~0.8     345~0.2   4567~0.3

Thanks.

Comment: Do the * always mean a new row? And is there any other relation in the data by row that you would need taken into account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because each of the rows is a different size, you either have to make a cell array, a structure, or deal with adding NaN or zero to a matrix. I chose to use a cell array, hope it is ok! If someone is better with regexp than me please comment, the output cells are now not perfect (i.e. show 345~ instead of 345~0.9) but I am sure it is a minor fix. Here is the code:

```
datfile = 'test.dat';
text = fileread(datfile);

row1 = regexp(text,'*[a-z]?\d+','match');
data(:,1) = row1';

row2 = regexp(text,'*[a-z]?\d+','split');
row2 = [row2(:,2:end)'];
for i = 1:size(row2,1)
   data{i,2} = regexp(row2{i},'\d+\S\d+\s','split');
end
```

What this creates is a cell array called data where the first column of every row is your *a682 id and the second column of each row is a cell with your data values. To get them you could use:

```
data{1}
```

to show the id

```
data{1,2}
```

to show the cell contents

```
data{1,2}{1}
```

to show the specific data point

This should work and is relatively simple!